# find path cross matrix with max sum forward then backward

Tags: algorithm

If I have a matrix, every element of the matrix is a non-negative number. I want to walk through the matrix from left-bottom corner to the right-top corner. In every step I can only move upward or rightward, and every visited element will be set to 0; after that, I walk back from the right-top corner to the left-bottom corner, every step I can only move downward or leftward.

My question is how to efficiently find a path with max sum.

Comment: @kajacx when I try to find the counter example, it seems that when the optimal can be a crossed path, I can always find another optimal with no-crossed path.

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://googlethatforme.pixeleco.com/?q=site%3Atopcoder.com+dynamic+programming+staradventure+SRM208&l=1

Comment: @fjardon how do you find that? did you meet this problem before?

Comment: @fjardon btw would please google another problem: we have a rectangle in 2-d space with size N x M, and this rectangle is composed with MN squares, where each square is of length 1. we draw a straight line to cross that rectangle, what is the max number of squares crossed by this line? (I was told that the original problem is in 3-d space.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's have a matrix with `N` rows and `M` columns and assume that `N>=2` and `M>=2`, otherwise the solution is trivial. I have an algorithm running in `O(max(M,N) * min(N,M)^4)` using dynamic programming.

First, let's prove that an optimal solution where the paths don't cross (except at start and end) always exists. We will take any solution and transform in into a non-crossing one without lowering the optimization function.

**Proof:**

Start by ensuring that the second path (from top-right to bottom-left) is always above or at the same row as the first path. Do that by taking a single section of both path where this isn't true, and swap them. Illustration:

[image: path swapping]

Then, remove one collision at a time. You can always find a collision such that at least one route is turning there, and you can change that path to avoid the collision. Repeat this until all collisions are removed. Illustration of one step:

[image: removing collison]

We see that not only no elements we removed from both paths combined, but more elements have been added, and all elements are non-negative, so the sum could only go up.

**The algorithm:**

We will only consider paths that don't cross, also I'll assume that `N<=M` (the matrix wide at least as height). Often we will add number from one column, that can be done quickly using [Prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum).

We will start at the first column. For each pair (i,j) such that `1<=i<j<=N` we will compute the *score* of that pair, that is the sum of how much can both paths cover starting at (1,1) and ending at (1,i) and (1,j) respectively. Example:

```
Matrix:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

score(1,1) = 7
score(1,3) = 12
score(2,3) = -inf (paths cannot cross)
```

Then we will compute score of each pair in the next column from the score of pairs in current column. For each pair in the next column, simply look at all the pairs in the previous column whose path can be extended to match the path of current column.

Finally, your answer is the score of pair `(N-1, N)` in the last column. I apologise for I am terrible at explaining algorithms over written media, I hope it's not completely un-understable.

Comment: Can you please explain how second column will be filled for the same matrix?And how to check if path are intersecting or not? It will be really great help.